# Kerberos authentication between Java application hosted in Netweaver 7.5 and Oracle database 19c

Tags: authentication, kerberos, portal

We have a Java application that is hosted in SAP Portal NW 7.5 which connects to Oracle DB through Custom JDBC datasource maintained in NWA.

Now our requirements is to include Kerberos authentication for connection between SAP Portal NW 7.5 and Oracle DB from Portal.

Kindly share your best practice approach and documents,OSS (if any) to achieve the requirements.

[AD integration requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4N47.jpg)

Regards,

Bharanidharan

Comment: if you wish to have user specific connection, then things will be complicated. If the connection is common across all the end users, then a common kerberos config will work - see the link Nirmala posted https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-991705F7-C2C5-4BA9-85D1-32749AE2FF64

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at the instructions present in [JDBC developer's guide?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-A27B26BE-82F3-4BA1-95B6-E09A789D532B)

Comment: Hi Nirmala,Thanks for your response. Kindly go through the diagram updated in my post and let me know if still i need to perform the shared system setups ? Query : Can't we Create and Replace current db user as a technical user in AD and update its credential details in SAP Portal which then authenticates the db how it was done currently?